# Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm: border array

Tags: string, algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

Here is a pseudo code for computing the border array in KMP.
p is the pattern

```
border[1]:=-1
i:=border[1]
for j=2,...,m
    while i >= 0 and p[i+1] != p[j-1] do i = border[i+1]
    i++
    border[j]:=i
```

I can execute the following pseudo code to compute the border array but the problem I am having right now is that I don't really understand the border array meaning how to interpret it.
For instance if the pattern does not equal at position (i+1) and (j-1) the variable i is set to border[i+1]. Why is that for example?

I realized the missing understanding when I tried to answer the question that three consecutive entries in a border array cannot differ by one from its predecessor. E.g. border[10]=3, border[11]=2, border[12]=1

I would appreciate a good explanation in order to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

OP 1."I don't really understand the border array meaning how to interpret it."

In this case, border means prefix and suffix of string.
Border value means longest `prefix == suffix`.
Gassa example - brackets `[]` mean `[prefix]==[suffix]`
why does border[3]=1?
`column:  [0]12[3]`
`string:  [a]bc[a]`
why does border[4]=2?
`column:  [01]2[34]`
`string:  [ab]c[ab]`
why does border[5]=1?
`column:  [0]1234[5]`
`string:  [a]bcab[a]`

OP 2."For instance if the pattern does not equal at position (i+1) and (j-1) the variable i is set to border[i+1]. Why is that for example?"

The comparison is checking if the last prefix/suffix character match
for example: `(p[i+1] != p[j-1])`
if they don't match, reduce comparison size of prefix/suffix from `border[j-1]+1 to border[i+1]`
for example: `i = border[i+1]`

OP 3."question that three consecutive entries in a border array cannot differ by one from its predecessor. E.g. border[10]=3, border[11]=2, border[12]=1"

When size of string increases by 1, two things can happen
Size of longest prefix/suffix can only increase by 1 or is less than that
In other words, `border[i+1]<=border[i]+1`
also, did you mean border array values canNOT differ more than one from its predecessor?
because here is an example of predecessor CAN differ more than one
`column:  01234`
`string:  babaa`
`border:  00120`

as you can see `border[3]=2` and `border[4]=0` so they differ by 2 not 1

sources:
I learn that border value means longest `prefix == suffix` from gassa link [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271856/understanding-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm/23595014#23595014)

Answer (score 0):

What you call the border array is the prefix function.
There are many explanations, see [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271856/understanding-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm/23595014#23595014), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), or just [google](https://www.google.ru/?#safe=off&q=knuth-morris-pratt+algorithm) an explanation more suitable for you.

As for the second part of your question, the following string is an example for the property you ask for:

```
column:  0123456
string:  abcabac
border:  0001210
```

Here, `border[4] = 2` because `ab = ab`, `border[5] = 1` because `a = a`, and `border[6] = 0`.

Whether all three values can be non-zero (for example, 3, 2, 1) is an interesting question.

Comment: I actually googled quite a bit but I couldn't find an explanation that helped for a better understanding. All the explanation I found were explaining how the the algorithm proceeds but not the really the idea behind it.

Comment: @tumbler I've actually explained KMP to students quite a number of times, using different approaches. There is usually a student who says, like, "hey, I heard the fourth explanation this time, and now it makes perfect sense!". However, most go like "meh, I do understand it... in general...". So, I don't know a universal way to explain KMP; in my experience, understanding it requires hearing - or reading - a few different explanations, until one of them "clicks" for you (but maybe not for others).