# how to compare two strings to find common substring

Tags: java, string

i get termination due to timeout error when i compile. Please help me

Given two strings, determine if they share a common substring. A substring may be as small as one character.

For example, the words "a", "and", "art" share the common substring "a" . The words "be" and "cat" do not share a substring.

**Input Format**

The first line contains a single integer , the number of test cases.

The following  pairs of lines are as follows:

The first line contains string s1 .
The second line contains string s2 .

**Output Format**

For each pair of strings, return YES or NO.

**my code in java**

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String s1,s2;
    int n;
    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    n=s.nextInt();
    while(n>0)
    {    
    int flag = 0;
        s1=s.next();

    s2=s.next();
    for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<s2.length();j++)
        {
            if(s1.charAt(i)==s2.charAt(j))
            {
                flag=1;
            }
        }
    }


        if(flag==1)
        {
            System.out.println("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
        n--;
}
}
```

}

any tips?

Comment: Two tips here:- in second loop use j=0 not j=i, second when flag=1, use break and come out of the loop, when you have found the match its unnecessary to iterate after that

Comment: why do you even have a `while` loop?

Comment: If you want more optimization then you can use other approach. You can use HashMaps in java to do it in O(n+m).

Comment: @ScaryWombat that 'n' is for 'n' number of queries, n number of test cases

Comment: Another tip: although the question asks for common substring, it is enough to find a common letter as you only have to give a yes/no answer.

Comment: Why not loop only on the first string and use `s2.indexOf(s1.charAt(i))` ? (Single char if satisfy boolean answer)

Comment: use matcher pattren.

Comment: Why is flag an `int`? That is what `boolean` is for ;)

Comment: I think this problem could be solved by KMP easily in linear time. So basically we just need to modify the algorithm slightly.

Comment: @ShravanKumar did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the timeout is probably: to compare two strings that each are 1.000.000 characters long, your code needs 1.000.000 * 1.000.000 comparisons, always.

There is a faster algorithm that only needs 2 * 1.000.000 comparisons. You should use the faster algorithm instead. Its basic idea is:

- for each character in s1: add the character to a set (this is the first million)
- for each character in s2: test whether the set from step 1 contains the character, and if so, return "yes" immediately (this is the second million)

Java already provides a BitSet data type that does all you need. It is used like this:

```
BitSet seenInS1 = new BitSet();
seenInS1.set('x');
seenInS1.get('x');
```

Comment: The timeout is probably because his code is expecting user input without even prompting the user.  *But* if it is not then your answer explains alot

Answer (score 3):

Below is my approach to get through the same HackerRank challenge described above

```
static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    String result="NO";
    Set<Character> set1 = new HashSet<Character>();

   for (char s : s1.toCharArray()){
       set1.add(s);
   }
   
    for(int i=0;i<s2.length();i++){
        if(set1.contains(s2.charAt(i))){
            result = "YES";
            break;
        }
    }
      return result;  
}
```

It passed all the Test cases without a time out issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're worried about execution time, if they give you an expected range of characters (for example `'a'` to `'z'`), you can solve it very efficiently like this:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Whatever {
    final static char HIGHEST_CHAR = 'z';  // Use Character.MAX_VALUE if unsure.

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final boolean[] characterSeen = new boolean[HIGHEST_CHAR + 1];

        mainloop:
        for (int word = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); word > 0; word--) {
            Arrays.fill(characterSeen, false);

            final String word1 = scanner.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < word1.length(); i++) {
                characterSeen[word1.charAt(i)] = true;
            }

            final String word2 = scanner.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < word2.length(); i++) {
                if (characterSeen[word2.charAt(i)]) {
                    System.out.println("YES");
                    continue mainloop;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

[The code was tested to work with a few inputs](https://ideone.com/eAJSBn#stdin).

This uses a fast array rather than slower sets, and it only creates one non-`String` object (other than the `Scanner`) for the entire run of the program. It also runs in O(n) time rather than O(n²) time.

The only thing faster than an array *might* be [the `BitSet` Roland Illig mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52847943/7208029).

If you wanted to go completely overboard, you could also potentially speed it up by:

- skipping the creation of a `Scanner` and all those `String` objects by using [`System.in.read(buffer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-) directly with a reusable `byte[]` buffer
- skipping the standard process of having to spend time checking for and properly handling negative numbers and invalid inputs on the first line by making your own very fast `int` parser that just assumes it's getting the digits of a valid nonnegative `int` followed by a newline

Comment: A BitSet is pretty much the same as an array, just a little nicer to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to solve this problem but solving this problem in linear time is a bit tricky.
Still, this problem can be solved in `linear` time. Just apply `KMP algorithm` in a trickier way.

Let's say you have 2 strings. Find the length of both strings first. Say length of `string 1` is bigger than `string 2`. Make `string 1` as your `text` and `string 2` as your `pattern`. If the length of the string is `n` and length of the pattern is `m` then time complexity of the above problem would be `O(m+n)` which is way faster than `O(n^2)`.

In this problem, you need to modify the `KMP algorithm` to get the desired result.

Just need to modify the KMP

```
public static void KMPsearch(char[] text,char[] pattern)
    {

        int[] cache = buildPrefix(pattern);

        int i=0,j=0;


        while(i<text.length && j<pattern.length)
        {

            if(text[i]==pattern[j])
                 {System.out.println("Yes");
                return;}
            else{


                if(j>0)
                    j = cache[j-1];
                else
                    i++;

                }

        }


        System.out.println("No");
        return;



    }
```

[Understanding Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271856/understanding-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm)

Answer (score -1):

There are two concepts involved in solving this question.

-Understanding that a single character is a valid substring.
-Deducing that we only need to know that the two strings have a common substring — we don’t need to know what that substring is.

Thus, the key to solving this question is determining whether or not the two strings share a common character.

To do this, we create two sets, a and b, where each set contains the unique characters that appear in the string it’s named after.

Because sets 26 don’t store duplicate values, we know that the size of our sets will never exceed the letters of the English alphabet.

In addition, the small size of these sets makes finding the intersection very quick.

If the intersection of the two sets is empty, we print NO on a new line; if the intersection of the two sets is not empty, then we know that strings and share one or more common characters and we print YES on a new line.

In code, it may look something like this

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    static Set<Character> a;
    static Set<Character> b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a = new HashSet<Character>();
            b = new HashSet<Character>();
            for(char c : scan.next().toCharArray()) {
                a.add(c);
            }
            for(char c : scan.next().toCharArray()) {
                b.add(c);
            }

            // store the set intersection in set 'a'
            a.retainAll(b);

            System.out.println( (a.isEmpty()) ? "NO" : "YES" );
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: seems overkill when a simple single loop of `s2.indexOf(s1.charAt(i))` would do the trick

Comment: @ScaryWombat,  I completely agree, but I thought that it would be good to show a different approach that is a bit off the track from loops.

Comment: @scarywombat Using an \$\mathcal O(n^2)\$ algorithm (your indexOf) seems overkill when there's also a faster \$\mathcal O(n)\$ algorithm. Note the timeout being mentioned in the question.

Comment: @RolandIllig *timeout error when i compile* I was not even sure what he was meaning

Comment: @ScaryWombat It's probably a contest or homework site where it compiles and runs the test inputs in one go.

Comment: A Java string is _not_ restricted to the "letters of the English alphabet". Do not assume this, ever.

Comment: @RolandIllig そうですね。

Answer (score -1):

```
public String twoStrings(String sOne, String sTwo) {
    if (sOne.equals(sTwo)) {
        return "YES";
    }

    Set<Character> charSetOne = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (Character c : sOne.toCharArray())
        charSetOne.add(c);

    Set<Character> charSetTwo = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (Character c : sTwo.toCharArray())
        charSetTwo.add(c);

    charSetOne.retainAll(charSetTwo);

    if (charSetOne.size() > 0) {
        return "YES";
    }

    return "NO";
}
```

This must work. Tested with some large inputs.

Answer (score -1):

**Python3**

```
def twoStrings(s1, s2):
    flag = False
    for x in s1:
        if x in s2:
            flag = True

    if flag == True: 
        return "YES"
    else:
        return "NO"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = 2
    text = [("hello","world"), ("hi","world")]
    for q_itr in range(q):
        s1 = text[q_itr][0]
        s2 = text[q_itr][1]

        result = twoStrings(s1, s2)
        print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2) {

       for (Character ch : s1.toCharArray()) {
            if (s2.indexOf(ch) > -1)
                return "YES";
        }
        return "NO";
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it